# Is there a way to add a sub panel to my detached garage?

Tags: subpanel

My main panel is full and I am trying to get electric in my detached garage with a sub panel but am unsure of any ways to do. My current main panel is an old Pushmatic and I’ve seen tandems for it but not sure if that’s safe.

What are my options to get a feed from this main panel to a new sub panel in the garage?[image][image][image]

Comment: I made a system for uploading big pictures. Email the picture(s) to shrink@picturepdf.com and you will get back an email with (a) shrunk images (~ 1.5 Meg., small enough for StackExchange) and (b) link you can copy to the "paste link" method of uploading images. Details at [picturepdf.com/shrink](https://picturepdf.com/shrink)

Comment: What is the size of your panel. I loved these panels years ago but most were smaller before code mandated 100a so a big one was not big by today’s standards. What type heating /cooking do you have gas electric? It may be possible to add a sub and move circuits to a sub. Then feed the garage if your panel is big enough.

Comment: Classic Pushmatic panels are "the best consumer panels ever made" according to many electricians, including being the *only* consumer panel with bolt-on breakers, which eliminates all "bus stab" problems. (which is what did in FPE and Zinsco). If you get rid of it, sell it on eBay.  Unfortunately the new Connecticut (pronounced "Cheep Chyneez") Electric breakers are rubbish. Let's see your panel and see what your options are.

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of your panel's door please?

Comment: It’s been added but not very descriptive in my opinion. Thank you

Comment: Are there labels on the inside right or left of the breaker box, and if so, can you get us photos of those?